# C# - populate grid with null values

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to **populate a grid** with values from an **Access** database, without success.

When I click the button from the grid, I get `null` value. Which is the problem? Can someone give me an idea/suggestion?

**My code is:**

```
private void btnComenzi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string owner = cboAgenti.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string AgentAsig = "";
        //string Data = "";
        string Client = "";
        //int Client = 0;
        //int NrCom = 0;
        string NrCom = "";
        double ValCom = 0;
        double Discount = 0;
        double ValFinala = 0;
        string Status = "";
        double Volum = 0;
        DateTime data = new DateTime();

        OleDbConnection conDataBase = RealizeazaConexiune();
        //select
        OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        selectCommand.Connection = conDataBase;
        string query1 = "SELECT Cod_Client, Cod_Comanda, Valoare_Comanda, Discount_Comanda, Valoare_Finala, Owner, Status_Comanda, Data_Comanda FROM Comenzi WHERE Owner = '" + cboAgenti.SelectedValue + "'";
        selectCommand.CommandText = query1;
       // OleDbDataReader myReader1 = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

       using (OleDbDataReader myReader1 = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (myReader1 != null && myReader1.Read())
            {
                // Data = myReader1[0].ToString(); Client = myReader1[1].ToString();
                Client = myReader1[0].ToString();
                NrCom = myReader1[1].ToString();
                ValCom = double.Parse(myReader1[2].ToString());
                Discount = double.Parse(myReader1[3].ToString());
                ValFinala = double.Parse(myReader1[4].ToString());
                AgentAsig = myReader1[5].ToString();
                Status = myReader1[6].ToString();
                data = DateTime.Parse(myReader1[7].ToString());
                Volum = Volum + ValFinala;
            }
        } 

        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
       // dr1[0] = Data;
        dr1[0] = Client;
        dr1[1] = NrCom;
        dr1[2] = ValCom;
        dr1[3] = Discount;
        dr1[4] = ValFinala;
        dr1[5] = AgentAsig;
        dr1[6] = Status;
        dr1[7] = data;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        dgvComenzi.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: have you placed breakpoints in the code.. does it enter the while loop..? also after your `dgvComenzi.DataSource = dt` you need to bind the dt to the grid call `dgvComenzi.Refresh()`; also you only need to do this in your While loop `while (myReader1.Read())` personally I would return the query to `Fill()` a datatable and bind the datatable to the DataSource..

Comment: @Iulia, make sure you set up the columns in the dgv so they match this data. That can be done in the designer or in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I've move some line with codes and, finally, it's works. I did'n succeed with Refreshing grid, but I'm keep trying.